# Combinations of rank and torsion attainable by $E/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Suppose $r\geq 0$ is a rank attainable by infinitely many elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $T$ be one of the fifteen finite abelian groups in Mazur's theorem.

Is there an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $E(\mathbb{Q})\approx \mathbb{Z}^r\times T$?

Comment: I think we don't understand the rank well enough to prove anything interesting. E.g. what is the set of $r$ attainable by infinitely many curves?

Comment: @WhatsUp I don't know what that set is but I assume $r$ is already a member of that set

Comment: I found a relevant paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.00077

Answer (score 5):

Dujella's webpage contains relevant information:

[Infinite families of elliptic curves with high rank and prescribed torsion](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/generic.html)

He also has pages describing rank records for [individual curves](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/tors.html) and for [curves defined over quadratic fields](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/%7Eduje/tors/torsquad.html).